# What is this "any"?

Tags: grammar

> Who that has heard a strain of music feared then lest he should speak extravagantly any more forever?

([Source](http://thoreau.eserver.org/walden18.html): Thoreau's *Walden*, Ch. 18, Para. 6)

I don't understand why "any more" is used here.

There is no negative here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the word 'lest' has the negative part.

Lest can be deciphered as  "so that not" or "to prevent any possibility that" and so on which have the negative sense.

For example consider the sentence: 'He tiptoed lest the guard should hear him'.

So in our sentence,

We can simply substitute 'lest' with the phrase 'to prevent any possibility that' which gives

"to prevent any possibility that he should speak extravagantly any more".

Hope now it makes sense using any more in the sentence.